# Moving a template to a resource dictionary, when said template contains code behind reference

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I'm creating a WPF application (Visual Studio 2010, C#, MVVM) in which there is a ListBox. I also have a template for the ListBox item, and the template is the source of the issue.

The template is getting pretty big and I want to move it to a resource dictionary. What's stopping me is that this line exists within it:

```
PreviewMouseRightButtonDown="OnContainingListMouseRightButtonDown"
```

The method which is run (on a right click event) makes sure the SelectedItem of the ListBox is the same as the one I'm right clicking on: that is to say, it sets the SelectedItem of the ListBox to the one that I right click on.

Obviously if I move the template, this part won't work anymore, but the template is getting rather large.

Is there a way around this?

Edit: I should have mentioned that I reference the items (such as the ListBox by its name) in the code behind as it stands. If I create a new code behind for the resource dictionary, I will no longer have access to those things.

Answer (score 1):

For example, your resource dictionary file name is *ListBoxStyle.xaml*. You should also create a C# file with name *ListBoxStyle.xaml.cs*. In your resource dictionary file you should add the following line:

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Class="CodeBehindNamespace.ListBoxStyle" ...>
```

It's the reference to your code behind. Your *ListBoxStyle.xaml.cs* content should be the following:

```
namespace CodeBehindNamespace
{
    public partial class ListBoxStyle : ResourceDictionary
    {
        public WindowStyle()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void OnContainingListMouseRightButtonDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        { ... }
    }
}
```